# How to save processed image in android

Tags: android, github, image-capture

I want to know how to save the processed image in a folder. The code is on [github](https://github.com/jhansireddy/AndroidScannerDemo/). It is a scanner. When the image is croping it will not saving the image. I want to save croped image.

The ResultFragment.java is the file for the output

Comment: You should post the problematic code here.

Comment: And post errors and exceptions from logcat if you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        OutputStream outStream = null;
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new
                Date());
        File file = new File(ScanConstants.IMAGE_PATH, timeStamp + "crop.jpg");

        try {
            outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);

            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outStream);
            outStream.flush();

            outStream.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {}
```

The file is ResultFragment.java and add the above code inside the  private class DoneButtonClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {